# Cannot create repository on github

Tags: github, repository

I'm not able to create public repositories on github. When I try to create a new repo a red message appears telling me `Something went wrong`

[image]

And, it actually doesn't matter what I type

[image]

Any suggestions what this might be ?

UPDATE: I found out that it is an issue related to my Chrome browser. If I use FF it works again. Now, I just signed out in Chrome and when I try to login again I get the following

[image]

UPDATE 2: A shutdown finally fixed the issue. It might be related to a full disk I had previously. We will never know :)

Comment: happened to me today o.o

Comment: Same problem with OSX Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit) - I've definately created repos with this browser before!  However, Firefox works fine for me to.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 42):

Sorry about that!
And l have resolved my problem met before.
Because l have installed a chrome extension named '`Allow-Control-Allow-Origin`' for debugging my web program sometimes.Now l disabled this extension when browse website normally and it is fixed.
I hope it can offer some help or inspiration for you.

Thanks

Comment: Disabling the CORS Chrome extension did the trick for me.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It must be one of the extensions you recently installed in your browser
e.g.  [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

will throw the same error if installed. Disable it and it will work.

Comment: Good answer and please provide extension link as well

Comment: I have added the link @Thamaraiselvam

Answer (score 2):

In my case, after turning off the AdBlock addon for chrome, when I logged in again, I was able to create the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Try login to your github account with another browser and create a repository, using that browser.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, Adblock extension caused **Create repository** button is disabled

Answer (score 0):

you could use the command

```
git init
git status
```

to check your current status of your repository but if you want to create a new remote repository you could use something like

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/USER-NAME/REPO-NAME.git
```

Comment: I've updated the question, it turns out it is some sort of issue with my Chrome browser